# Enabling on-screen keyboard in simulator

Tags: blackberry-simulator, blackberry-10

How can I enable the on-screen, virtual keyboard in the BlackBerry 10 alpha simulator?

I'm having some troubles inputting text into my ported Android application, and had read that the PlayBook simulator also had problems with inputting text through the host PC's keyboard.

I've enabled "Keypress Pop-up" (not knowing what it does) in the "On-screen keyboard" setting in the simulator's settings, but it appears to have no effect:
[image: On-Screen Keyboard settings]

Is there any way to get the on-screen keyboard to appear, so I can test using that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I discovered that the on-screen keyboard only appears when dragging in from the **bottom-left corner**.

Furthermore, I discovered that in portrait mode, the keyboard doesn't display correctly:

[image: Simulator in portrait; keyboard doesn't appear correctly]

To get the simulator in landscape mode, drag from the **bottom-right corner**; the keyboard then does appear correctly:

[image: Simulator in landscape; keyboard appears correctly]

Incidentally, this didn't resolve my woes with text input. Since it works so sporadically, I believe this is simply due to the simulator still being in alpha. In fact, at the moment, various keys map incorrectly, such as "3" mapping to "1" and "4" to "8", but most of them simply not at all. This may have to do with `android:inputType="number"`.

Comment: Without any modifications, the app worked correctly on the Dev Alpha device, so the above problems are indeed specific to the emulator.